# How to Access java Classes from Ui5 Application/Program?

Tags: java, sapui5

we are Developing the Ui5 Screens for an existing Application which uses SQL server Data. the current applications are accessing the data using java Classes, so can anyone suggest How to access these Java Classes from UI5 Program.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Java classes directly from your UI5 application. Since your Java classes are interacting with the SQL Server data, you can write your sql statements and access your sql server data directly from your UI5 application using EJB and Rest service.
For more details regarding this you can check this blog:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/07/30/sap-ui5-application-is-connected-to-3rd-party-system-sql-database-using-ejb-rest-servicev